# Unable to get current date time using javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

```
var now = new Date();
var dateString = now.getMonth() + "-" + now.getDate() + "-" + now.getFullYear() + " "
+ now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();
```

here month is not displayed correctly.

Example if output is december it prints november

`now.getMonth() +1` would display the correct month.

I am looking for a more better approach.

My application has to choose between two radiobuttons.the first option should return the current system date and time and other returns date and time selected from jsp.
On selecting either of the two options,it should return a date in a specific format to the controller.

Comment: What do you mean more stable ? Javascript month is a zero based number and it will always return 1 less that what we expect. So getMonth()+1 is the way to go about it.

Comment: i was in search of an alternate better approach

Comment: And that was the question I had asked as well. What do you mean better here? What improvements are you looking for ?

Comment: What about `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12][new.getMonth()]`? I'm sure we can find even more complicated approaches to an *absofsckinglutely simple* problem. Just get over it and write `+1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) by definition returns month from 0 to 11.

If you are not used to this, you can change the prototype of a `Date` object:

```
Date.prototype.getFixedMonth = function(){
    return this.getMonth() + 1;
}

new Date().getFixedMonth(); //returns 12 (December)
new Date("January 1 2012").getFixedMonth //returns 1 (January)
```

But this is not recommended at all.

---

### Another approach

You can do this too if you want:

```
Date.prototype._getMonth = Date.prototype.getMonth;
Date.prototype.getMonth = function(){       //override the original function
    return this._getMonth() + 1;
}

new Date().getMonth(); //returns 12 (December)
new Date("January 1 2012").getMonth //returns 1 (January)
```

Comment: Could you please suggest another approach?

Comment: @divyanair - Can you be more specific of what you want?

Comment: got system date using var now = new Date();now i need to get this date in say dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss format

Comment: @divyanair - If you prefer an extra library, [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) will do all the works for you. Quick and easy! :) `moment().format("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: was looking for something like this

Answer (score 2):

`getMonth()` is supposed to return the Month as index from 0 to 11 (0 is January and 11 is December). So, what you're getting is the expected return value.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Function

```
 function GetTime_RightNow() {
        var currentTime = new Date()
        var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
        var day = currentTime.getDate()
        var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
        alert(month + "/" + day + "/" + year)
    }
```

Comment: This seems to be the same approach as i used but as a function.